# Making subversion use system accounts

Tags: debian, svn

I'm setting up a subversion server for hold my code for a website I've been working on, and I'm trying to do it all though svnserve, however I need to be able to access it using the system accounts, and I'd prefer not to have to copy/paste usernames and passwords into a plaintext file.

It's a debian server, and PAM is enabled. How can I get svn to authenticate off system user accounts?

Comment: Might be nice to get Apache HTTP auth to use system accounts and use mod_svn too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using svn over ssh?  This is a good blog entry: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/531.cfm

Comment: we use a non-standard port for ssh, how would we specify it. Most people who would be accessing it are not doing so through the commandline or even in linux so .subversion/config and adding a tunnel wouldn't work

Comment: %AppData%/Subversion/config on windows.